# My random image bot tries to pull images from the main folder instead of the specified folder

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried several times to get this to work but can't figure out how to direct the bot to the proper folder.

I always get this error when I run the command

> (node:15532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Discordbot\93c5b877d8afcf7a9590fcb149e849c53c6cc1ed.jpg'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./pics/'); // I thought this would direct it to where it neeeds to be

module.exports = {
    execute(message, args){
   var item = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
   var item = new MessageAttachment(item);
   message.channel.send(item)
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the folder "pics" a folder in the main root or a sub folder?

Comment: It is in the same folder as index.js and package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you use an absolute path.

1. You can use `__dirname` which will point to a directory of the current file.

   var files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'pics'));
2. You can use `require.main.filename` which will point to the directory where `package.json` is placed (main directory)

   var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
   var files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(appDir, 'pics'));

Comment: `var files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'pics'));`

Comment: I did this and it's going to my commands folder instead of the main folder. how do I prevent this?

Comment: @AsukaSZN I have updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: I see. Should pics be left as just 'pics' or ''/pics/'?

Comment: @AsukaSZN `path.join` will handle the slashes. Just use 'pics'